# How to make the Pi an acces point

Tags: networking

I'm trying to make my Pi into a wired (for my T.V) access point. I have followed [this tutorial](http://itsacleanmachine.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/wifi-access-point-with-raspberry-pi.html), the final hostapd.conf file launches just fine. However, when I connect the Ethernet cable to my T.V, it doesn't actually send any info, it connects, but doesn't work. Also, when I take my Ethernet cable out of the pi, wireless connectivity works from my laptop, however again, it only connects yet doesn't actually connect on the internet. Does anybody know how I can make my Pi be able to be a **wired** hotspot so I can connect my T.V to the internet.

I believe it's Raspberry Pi Model B, with Raspbian OS installed.

Comment: If the Raspberry Pi has an Ethernet Port, then it's a model B

Answer (score 1):

So let's get this straight.  You're looking to do the following:

[INTERNET] <==> [Wifi Hotspot] < - - > [PI] <==> [TV]

Wired connection <==>

Wireless connection < - - >

You don't need to run hostapd on the Pi.  I would do the following:

1. Confirm your internet is working.
2. Confirm your Router is working.
3. Configure your Pi as a wireless client for the router.  Confirm the Pi can connect to the internet.
4. You now need to configure your Pi as a [BRIDGE](http://users.sdsc.edu/~glockwood/sa/rpi-wifi-bridge.php). [An even better link](http://rbnrpi.wordpress.com/project-list/wifi-to-ethernet-adapter-for-an-ethernet-ready-tv/)
5. Plug your TV into the Pi and you should be good.

Comment: Just a FYI, but that link is actually setting up the Pi as a Router, not as a bridge.

Answer (score 1):

Just forward packages from Wired interface to Wireless interface.

1. Do you need DHCP? If so, setup [dnsmasq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq) (a dhcp server and dns server).
2. Setup package forwarding using [iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo?action=show&redirect=Iptables), using some script like:

   `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE`

   192.168.0.0 is your wired network address.
3. Enable ip forwarding

   `sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Answer (score 0):

I happened to come across this article while looking for something else: http://raspberry-at-home.com/hotspot-wifi-access-point/

Unfortunately I can't vouch for the contents since I haven't tried it, but I thought it might be useful. Let me know if it works for you.